# Get original Response after existingResponse=Replace

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I'm use existingResponse="Replace" in my web.config

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="400"/>
      <error statusCode="400" path="/Error/BadRequest" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
 </httpErrors>
```

Called method in my ApiController

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    return BadRequest("original");
}
```

Can I get "original" text in the handled method in ErrorController?

```
public ActionResult BadRequest()
{
    //HttpContext.Request???
    return View();
}
```

I know that I can use existingResponse="PassThrough" but isn't in this case.